# C# bit shift: is this behavior in the spec, a bug, or fortuitous?

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I was working with bit shift operators (see my question [Bit Array Equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320754/bit-array-equality)) and a SO user pointed out a bug in my calculation of my shift operand--I was calculating a range of [1,32] instead of [0,31] for an int. (Hurrah for the SO community!)

In fixing the problem, I was surprised to find the following behavior:

```
-1 << 32 == -1
```

In fact, it would seem that `n << s` is compiled (or interpreted by the CLR--I didn't check the IL) as `n << s % bs(n)` where bs(n) = size, in bits, of n.

I would have expected:

```
-1 << 32 == 0
```

It would seem that the compiler is realizing that you are shifting beyond the size of the target and correcting your mistake.

This is purely an academic question, but does anyone know if this is defined in the spec (I could not find anything at [7.8 Shift operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377(VS.71).aspx)), just a fortuitous fact of undefined behavior, or is there a case where this might produce a bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the relevant part of the spec is here:

> For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:
>
> - When the type of x is int or uint, the shift count is given by the
>       low-order five bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed
>       from count & 0x1F.
> - When the type of x is long or ulong, the shift count is given by the
>       low-order six bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed
>       from count & 0x3F.

If the resulting shift count is zero, the shift operators simply return the value
of x.

The value `32` is `0x20`.  The expression `0x20 & 0x1F` evaluates to `0`.  Therefore, the shift count is zero, and no shift is done; the expression `-1 << 32` (or any `x << 32`) just returns the original value.

Comment: Ah, of course. I read that but my mind must have blanked out. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!